# How to set default value for Input fields of datetime-local type created dynamically using Vuejs/Nuxtjs?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, nuxt.js, datetime-local

I am creating a few input fields of type `datetime-local` in `Vuejs/Nuxtjs` dynamically. I would like to set the default value for all these input fields as `2022-04-21T14:27:27.000`. How to do it?

For the direct field, we can assign the value using the `v-model` but I am a bit unsure about how to set a default value for all the fields of `datetime-local`. If I am not wrong there is an option in Vanilla JavaScript to get all fields of a certain type and change the value, is there a way to achieve the same using `Vuejs/Nuxtjs`.

Following is the code I have so far:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="addField" class="btn btn-info">
      Add Field
    </button>

    <div v-for="field in fieldArray" :key="field.ID" class="form-group">
      <input
        v-model="field.time"
        type="datetime-local"
        class="form-control"
        step="1"
        value="2022-04-21T14:27:27.000"
        @change="timeChange(field.ID)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fieldCount: 0,
      fieldArray: [],
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    let now = new Date();
    now.setMinutes(now.getMinutes() - now.getTimezoneOffset());
    now.setSeconds(now.getSeconds(), 0);
    now = now.toISOString().slice(0, -1);
    //I would like to set this "now" time value for all the created fields of input type datetime-local
    console.log("Current Time : " + now);
  },
  methods: {
    //Add field
    addField() {
      const fieldObj = { ID: this.fieldCount, time: "" };
      this.fieldArray.push(fieldObj);
    },
    //Time change
    timeChange(ID) {
      console.log("ID : " + ID);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.fieldArray, null, 4));
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

All I would like to do is set the default time for all the `datetime-local` fields within my component. Is there any way to do it? I am able to achieve this for single field but not for the fields which is created dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="addField" class="btn btn-info">
      Add Field
    </button>

    <div v-for="field in fieldArray" :key="field.ID" class="form-group">
      <input
        v-model="field.time"
        type="datetime-local"
        class="form-control"
        step="1"
        value="2022-04-21T14:27:27.000"
        @change="timeChange(field.ID)"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      fieldCount: 0,
      fieldArray: [],
      now: null,
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.now = new Date();
    this.now.setMinutes(this.now.getMinutes() - this.now.getTimezoneOffset());
    this.now.setSeconds(this.now.getSeconds(), 0);
    this.now = this.now.toISOString().slice(0, -1);
    //I would like to set this "now" time value for all the created fields of input type datetime-local
    console.log("Current Time : " + this.now);
  },
  methods: {
    //Add field
    addField() {
      const fieldObj = { ID: this.fieldCount, time: this.now };
      this.fieldArray.push(fieldObj);
    },
    //Time change
    timeChange(ID) {
      console.log("ID : " + ID);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.fieldArray, null, 4));
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Dates are always hard.

The HTML input element with type datetime-local is odd. While it accepts a JavsScript date as input, it outputs a string... I would create a *proxy* component to handle this.

Take a look at [this playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

```html
// DateInput.vue
<template>
  <input :value="modelValue"
         @input="$emit('update:modelValue', new Date($event.target.value))"
         type="datetime-local" />
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: ["modelValue"],
  emits: ["update:modelValue"],
}
</script>
```

```html
// Parent.vue
<template>
  <div>
    <button type="button" @click="addField" class="btn btn-info">
      Add Field
    </button>
    <div v-for="field in fieldArray" :key="field.ID" class="form-group">
      {{field.ID}}
      <DateInput v-model="field.time"></DateInput> {{field.time}}
    </div>
    <hr />
    {{fieldCount}}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DateInput from './DateInput.vue'
export default {
  components: { DateInput },
  data() {
    return {
      fieldArray: [],
    };
  },
  computed: {
    fieldCount () {
      return this.fieldArray.length
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addField() {
      this.fieldArray.push({ ID: this.fieldCount, time: new Date() });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```